# Java: how to add text to each array item?

Tags: java, parsing

I have a Java array of strings.

I need to add some text before and after each array element.

```
e.g. ["first","second",.. "last"]
```

should become

```
["<title>first</title>","<author>second</author>" ...]
```

and so on. Should I use a for statement ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve by doing something like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strs = { "first", "second", "last" };
        String[] tags = { "title", "author", "something" };

        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
            strs[i] = String.format("<%s>%s</%1$s>", tags[i], strs[i]);

        String result = "";
        for (String str : strs)
            result += str;

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<title>first</title><author>second</author><something>last</something>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to remove the "[" "]" from the output string ? Should I cut the strings ?

Comment: and the commas as well! I guess I cannot use toString function

Comment: If you wanted to change how the text has printed, you could write another for loop and iterate over the Array yourself and use `println` on each item separately.